# border beside accordion not updating

Tags: jquery, html, css, border, accordion

I created a html page with an accordion menu in a div element.
The div has a simple border styling on the right of the element using

```
height:100%;
 border-right-width:2px;
 border-right-style:solid;
 border-right-color:#4875B4;
```

This all works nicely, however, whenever I expand an accordion header the border does not expand also(I thought it would as height is set to 100%).
Is this a known issue, I can't find any discussions on it. Has anyone experienced this, is there a fix?

EDIT 28TH 05
This is the jsfiddle showing this issue http://jsfiddle.net/ZxnAd/
Please select "section 3" to see the border not extending with accordion

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `height: 100%` is that it usually doesn't work, because the question is not answered—"100% of what?" Unless the container has a set height, there isn't a context for % height of an inner element; yet setting heights like that usually isn't a good idea. It might be possible to do what you want in a different way, but you'll need to show us an example.

EDIT: OK, given the link, why not try this instead:

```
.accordion {
    border-left: 2px solid #190; 
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I've updated my post with a jsfiddle showing issue, any suggestions are welcomed

Comment: The issue with this is, I hide my accordion when the page is first loaded, so the border will only reappear once I've unhidden it. This is why I need to keep the border on the menu div. Is there some jquery trickery I can use to overcome?